# Javascript redirection title with window.location.title

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how I can fix this problem because I only see undefined title as result.

My page title is "My Test Page" on `exemple1.com`:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
     window.location = "http://exemple2.com/?keyword="+window.location.title;
 </script>
```

I would like that it redirect to

```
http://exemple2.com/?keyword=My Test Page
```

However, for the moment it looks like

```
http://exemple2.com/?keyword=undefined
```

Comment: [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#Properties) doesn't have a `title` property

Answer (score 1):

[`document.title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/title) is what you're looking for

```
window.location = `http://exemple2.com/?keyword=${document.title}`;
```

Comment: thx you Miguel your answer is correct (u where the first) i have vote for you but it does not show since i have low post count

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing called `window.location.title` so if your page title is "My Test Page" and you want your link to

```
http://exemple2.com/?keyword=My Test Page
```

then you should use `document.title`

try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://exemple2.com/?keyword="+document.title;
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The var you're looking for is document.title, not window.location.title.

Answer (score 0):

From

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.location = "http://exemple2.com/?keyword="+window.location.title;
 </script>
```

To

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 window.location = "http://exemple2.com/?keyword="+document.title;
 </script>
```

You can always go to dev tools and print location or document to see what method they have